# Convergence of sequence of one to one correspondence sequence.

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve this problem but am struggling with it.
The problem is as below.

Let $ a_n$ be a convergent sequence with $A =\displaystyle  \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$. Suppose that $f: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is a one to one correspondence. Define a new sequence by $b_n=a_{f(n)}$ .Prove or disprove : $A =\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n$.

Please let me know how to proceed with it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please be sure to check this guide of MathJax formatting so you can correctly format your future questions (or answers): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @hardmath: why should $a_n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @Reveillark sure I will learn of it .

Comment: @hardmath Yes the question asks for bn to converge to the same value A, and I don think it means an is a sequence of natural numbers.If so it wouldnt converge isnt it ?

Comment: @user251257:  I'm trying to clarify what domain the $a_n$ belong to.  The only domain mentioned is $\mathbb{N}$, but I would be happy to have the OP clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. I will prove it for a real valued sequence. If you like, you can translate it into any topological space.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists some $p_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $p\ge p_0$ it follows $|a_p - A| < \epsilon$.

Let $S = \{ n_0\in\mathbb N \mid \forall n\ge n_0 : f(n) \ge p_0 \}$.
Now, assume the contrary that $S$ is empty. That is, for every $n_0\in\mathbb N$ there exists some $n\ge n_0$ with $f(n) < p_0$. It would contradict that $f$ is injective. Thus, $S$ is not empty and we can select an element $n_0\in S$. For every $n\ge n_0$ it follows $f(n) \ge p_0$ and
$$ |a_{f(n)} - A| < \epsilon. $$

Comment: could you please explain the the part where you define the set 'S'.

Comment: you need to show that there exists some $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$ it follows $|a_{f(n)} - A| < \epsilon$. $S$ is simply a set of possible $n_0$. If $S$ is empty, you would get infinite many $n_1, n_2, \dotsc$ such that $f(n_k) < p_0$. That is obviously not possible.